# Join two tables using Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm learning symfony framework as of the moment and I am very new to this framework.

what I am trying to do is to join two tables named `movies` and `genres`

and what I want is to achieve this using the query builder and also what is the advantage of using the `Query Builder`?

as of the moment I am using this to query all movies:

```
$movies = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Movies')
                ->findAll();
```

I'm really new to this so please bear with me.

Comment: I think you should better use doctrine mappings http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: @NikolayKrasnov Hi sir this is very informative.. btw, I'm creating my database table from my Model Class.. so on my own understanding it is somewhat like C# mvc Code First Approach... but unlike on C# I create the model class on my IDE.. however on symfony I'm using the console to create the model class.. so for example if I have genre class model.. and if I create the movie model class should I include the genre there not just the genre_id?

Comment: @SamTengWong you would add `$genre` (if it  is one to many relation) Then you could do `$movie->getGenre()` to get the genre of your movie. You really have to use the `Doctrine ORM`

Comment: @SamTengWong This [Doctrine createQueryBuilder and createQuery examples](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/znlh/doctrine-createquerybuilder-and-createquery-examples) might be useful for you. Also if you're learning Symfony and Doctrine, there are many examples in that blog.